# Prevent apps from pausing Google Play Music

Tags: music, google-play-music

Some applications tend to pause my music. I know it is paused because the Google Play Music widget shows the play button and pressing it resumes the song. Is it possible to remove that function or privilege?

Music : Google Play Music

App : Learn SQL

Phone is LG G3.
Android 5.0

Phone is not rooted. Problem is not intermittent and can be reproduced by clicking on a course inside the Learn SQL app while music is playing.

I am also using Avast Battery Saver.

Comment: Contact the developer of the problematic app and send them a link to this question. You can find the email of any developer on the app page on Google Play

Comment: OK. I Will do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is determined by Play Music, which gets notified when another app requests audio focus (as per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#audiofocus)).  Unless there is an option in Play Music's settings to disable this behavior, or perhaps a mute function in the "problem" app, there's nothing you can do about it.

It's also possible for other apps to pause by sending an [`ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON), which is not protected — which again means there's nothing you can do about it unless those apps have an option to not send it.